# $Browser not detecting ipad and showing as desktop

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, browser

This is my simple component to check form factor and for iPad, it shows the desktop.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    {!$Browser.isTablet}
    {!$Browser.isPhone}
    {!$Browser.isAndroid}
    {!$Browser.formFactor}
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was working earlier. However, with the introduction of Lightning Experience on iPad Browser, it seems that the form-factor needs to be "Desktop", otherwise if it is "Phone" the classic UI is loaded.

That being the case, the $Browser checks are no longer evaluating correctly on iPad type devices as they don't seem to be checked if you are on "Desktop" form-factor.
For example:isIOS, isIPad, isTablet all return False.

When I run the code snippet

```
<aura:component>
   {!$Browser.formFactor}
   {!$Browser.isTablet}
   {!$Browser.isIOS}
   {!$Browser.isTablet}
</aura:component>
```

you can observe that Browser returns

```
Desktop
False
False
False
```

whereas Salesforce Mobile App returns:

```
Phone
False
True
False
```

Upon checking internally with the salesforce product team,we have a bug logged (W-8147075) and it seems that with the recent changes that Apple has made to UserAgents, we no longer have a good reliable way to run this logic. As such, our team is working on deprecating some of these checks. Our documentation will be updated to reflect this information in the coming release(Safe harbor). But, this boils down to changes made on the platform side (Apple/iOS), that affected the mapping/logic and those changes no longer allow for definite and reliable isolation of iOS iPad and MacOS devices.

There is no plan by the product team in the near future to include these features as it is dependent on Apple device updates.

Let me know if you have any follow up queries.

Regards,

Salesforce Support

Comment: what would be the workaround for this issue? we have code in lots of places having different view for ipad vs desktop which is breaking. is there a possible workaround?

Comment: I dont think there's a way to handle this via code/configuration. Can you try to change "Request Desktop website" from ON to OFF(https://www.browserstack.com/guide/request-desktop-site-on-iphone) and see if it helps? If yes, to use $Browser attribute either you will have to let your end users know about this limitation or you can add an Alert pop up in your custom code stating 'Ensure desktop site request is turned off"

Comment: @shaan Let me know if the above works for your scenario or if you have any follow up queries. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window.screen.width property. Usually iPad/tablet max width would be 1024. It may not the perfect way but majority of laptops (13 inch and above) should've greater width than this. So it should work.